# Get next available number from specific available range of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

In my system I have to provide the next available number to a new customer; this number will be used as an account number. Sometimes I will have to change the range of available numbers if the particular account numbers are not available anymore.

So..

Table 1 holds customers and their account number:

```
Customer1 | 210314
Customer2 | 210313
Customer3 | 210312
```

Table 2 holds the range of account numbers to choose from:

```
StartNumber | 210300
EndNumber   | 210452
```

I want to be able to select the next available number `(Max(accountnumber)+1)` and check if it is in the range of the number series in Table 2. In this case it would be 210315, but if I were to change the number series in Table 2, for example, to

```
StartNumber | 220000
EndNumber   | 220999
```

it would then give 220001 as a next available number.

Could someone give me an example of solution and sorry for the long description :)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a sequence for this, with a min and max value and nocycle, instead of your range table? And then modify the sequence when your range needs to change, assuming you would never then reuse the same range? Anything else will need to handle simultaneous requests (i.e. serialise).

Comment: I agree with Alex, but if you can't use a sequence for some reason, this isn't too hard. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: In table2, are StartNumber and EndNumber on the same record or different records? If they are on different records, is there any way to link them together?

Answer (score 0):

On table1 can you add an Identity column that that auto increments by 1, but has a starting seed of your Table2.StartNumber column?
i.e.

```
Id int not null identity(2200, 1)
```

Each time you then enter a value into table1 the Id column will increase by 1, give you the current working value. You can the select it as Max(Id) + 1 to get the next value.

You can reset the identity seed each time you reset the range of numbers.

```
create table test (
Id int not null identity(2200, 1), 
CustomerName nvarchar(100)
)

insert into test (CustomerName) values ('Customer1')
insert into test (CustomerName) values ('Customer2')
insert into test (CustomerName) values ('Customer3')

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('test', RESEED, 4500)

insert into test (CustomerName) values ('Customer4')
insert into test (CustomerName) values ('Customer5')
insert into test (CustomerName) values ('Customer6')

select * from test
```

Yields the results:

```
Id      CustomerName
2200    Customer1
2201    Customer2
2202    Customer3
4501    Customer4
4502    Customer5
4503    Customer6
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an auto-incrementing identity column in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming StartNumber and EndNumber are columns on Table2, try:

```
select greatest(min(m.max_acct)+1, min(r.StartNumber)+1) NextAccount
from (select max(AccountNumber) max_acct from Table1) m
join Table2 r on r.EndNumber >= m.max_acct+1
```

Comment: greatest is not a group function

Comment: I wasn't using it as a group function, although your comment did remind me that `m.max_acct` needed to be inside a group function - I have now amended the query accordingly. Also, **you still haven't clarified whether StartNumber and EndNumber are on the same record or different records in table2**, despite the fact that I asked two days ago.